# How To Change Contents Of A CAEmitterCell In A CAEmitterLayer Particle Emitter

Tags: ios, optimization, core-animation, caemitterlayer, caemittercell

**Background**

I have a function that creates a core animation emitter layer that animates `myImage1`, in the code below.

I want to change `myImage1` to `myImage2` to `myImage3` and back to `myImage1` after a delay of 10 seconds or every time a button is tapped.

I’ve tried unsuccessfully. The code `myEmitterChange()` is executed but the image doesn’t change in the core animation emitter layer. What needs to be corrected in the code below?

---

**Questions**

1 - How do I change the emitter layer image once the CAEmitterLayer is added to a view ?

2 - How do I completely stop the CAEmitterLayer animation and remove it entirely from the view?

---

**Code**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var myEmitterLayer = CAEmitterLayer()
var myEmitterCell = CAEmitterCell()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    
    myEmitter()
    
    self.perform(#selector(self.myEmitterChange), with: nil, afterDelay: 10)

}

@objc func myEmitterChange() {
    
    print("Did I Change?")
    
    myEmitterCell.color = UIColor.orange.cgColor
    myEmitterCell.contents = UIImage(named: "myImage2")!.cgImage
    
}


func myEmitter() {
        
    myEmitterCell.birthRate = 1
    myEmitterCell.color = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    myEmitterCell.contents = UIImage(named: "myImage1")!.cgImage
    myEmitterCell.lifetime = 15
    myEmitterCell.scale = 0.25
    myEmitterCell.scaleSpeed = 0.025
    myEmitterCell.velocity = 50
    myEmitterCell.velocityRange = 50
    myEmitterCell.spin = -2

    myEmitterLayer.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
    myEmitterLayer.birthRate = 1
    myEmitterLayer.emitterMode = CAEmitterLayerEmitterMode.outline
    myEmitterLayer.emitterPosition = CGPoint(x: (view.bounds.size.width * 0.5), y: (view.bounds.size.height * 0.5))
    myEmitterLayer.emitterShape = CAEmitterLayerEmitterShape.circle
    myEmitterLayer.emitterSize = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
    myEmitterLayer.renderMode = CAEmitterLayerRenderMode.oldestLast
    myEmitterLayer.emitterCells = [myEmitterCell]

    view.layer.addSublayer(myEmitterLayer)
    
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Changing the image**

1 - Add in the `myEmitter()` function a `name` property to `myEmitterCell`.

```
    myEmitterCell.name = "myEmitterCellName"
```

2 - Add in the `myEmitterChange()` function a `setValue` method to `myEmitterLayer`.

```
    myEmitterLayer.setValue(UIColor.orange.cgColor, forKeyPath: "emitterCells.myEmitterCellName.color")
    myEmitterLayer.setValue(UIImage(named: "myImage2")!.cgImage, forKeyPath: "emitterCells.myEmitterCellName.contents")
```

3 - Remove in the `myEmitterChange()` function the `myEmitterCell.color` and `myEmitterCell.contents` lines.

```
//    myEmitterCell.color = UIColor.orange.cgColor
//    myEmitterCell.contents = UIImage(named: "myImage2")!.cgImage
```

**Stopping the animation**

1 - Add in the `myEmitterStop()` function a `setValue` method to `myEmitterLayer`.

```
myEmitterLayer.setValue(0, forKeyPath: "emitterCells.myEmitterCellName.birthRate")
```

---

**Code**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var myEmitterLayer = CAEmitterLayer()
var myEmitterCell = CAEmitterCell()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    
    myEmitter()
    
    self.perform(#selector(self.myEmitterChange), with: nil, afterDelay: 10)

    self.perform(#selector(self.myEmitterStop), with: nil, afterDelay: 20)  // <- Add this line

}


@objc func myEmitterStop() {

    print("Did I Stop?")

    myEmitterLayer.setValue(0, forKeyPath: "emitterCells.myEmitterCellName.birthRate")  // <- Add this line

}


@objc func myEmitterChange() {
    
    print("Did I Change?")
    
//    myEmitterCell.color = UIColor.orange.cgColor   // <- Remove this line
//    myEmitterCell.contents = UIImage(named: "myImage2")!.cgImage   // <- Remove this line
    
    myEmitterLayer.setValue(UIColor.orange.cgColor, forKeyPath: "emitterCells.myEmitterCellName.color")  // <- Add this line
    myEmitterLayer.setValue(UIImage(named: "myImage2")!.cgImage, forKeyPath: "emitterCells.myEmitterCellName.contents")  // <- Add this line
    
}


func myEmitter() {
    
    myEmitterCell.name = "myEmitterCellName" // <- Add this line
        
    myEmitterCell.birthRate = 1
    myEmitterCell.color = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    myEmitterCell.contents = UIImage(named: "myImage1")!.cgImage
    myEmitterCell.lifetime = 15
    myEmitterCell.scale = 0.25
    myEmitterCell.scaleSpeed = 0.025
    myEmitterCell.velocity = 50
    myEmitterCell.velocityRange = 50
    myEmitterCell.spin = -2

    myEmitterLayer.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
    myEmitterLayer.birthRate = 1
    myEmitterLayer.emitterMode = CAEmitterLayerEmitterMode.outline
    myEmitterLayer.emitterPosition = CGPoint(x: (view.bounds.size.width * 0.5), y: (view.bounds.size.height * 0.5))
    myEmitterLayer.emitterShape = CAEmitterLayerEmitterShape.circle
    myEmitterLayer.emitterSize = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
    myEmitterLayer.renderMode = CAEmitterLayerRenderMode.oldestLast
    myEmitterLayer.emitterCells = [myEmitterCell]

    view.layer.addSublayer(myEmitterLayer)
    
    }

}
```